# How to SELECT from object type column in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, object, select, oracle11g

Hy guys,
I have following two Oracle objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE car AS OBJECT( 
name VARCHAR( 80 ) 
) NOT FINAL;
```

And also, there is another object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE truck UNDER car ( 
doors NUMBER,
seats NUMBER 
);
```

There is also following table:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles (
id NUMBER NOT NULL,
vehicle car,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here is some data:

```
INSERT INTO vehicles ( id, vehicle ) VALUES ( 1, truck( 'ford', 4, 4 ) );
INSERT INTO vehicles ( id, vehicle ) VALUES ( 2, truck( 'toyota', 4, 5 ) );
```

Finally, my question is:
**How to select only number of doors and number of seats from vehicle table column?**

I tried following but it does not work:

```
SELECT v.vehicle.doors AS doors AS seats FROM vehicles v;
```

I got following error:

```
ORA-00904: "V"."VEHICLE"."DOORS": invalid identifier
```

Only parameter that i can get without any error is one from car object.

FYI, I am using Oracle 11g on CentOS 6.2

Cheers,
Bojan

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to use the TREAT function to get the database engine to treat VEHICLE as a TRUCK, as in:

```
SELECT ID, TREAT(vehicle AS TRUCK).DOORS FROM VEHICLES
```

Share and enjoy.