# INSERT SELECT with SELECT's column object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this code.

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
  USERNAME NVARCHAR2(30),
  USER_TYPE VARCHAR2(13)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_USER_TYPE IS OBJECT(
  USER_TYPE VARCHAR2(13),
  USER_LEVEL NUMBER(38, 0)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_USER IS OBJECT(
  USERNAME NVARCHAR2(30),
  USER_TYPE OBJ_USER_TYPE
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NST_USERS IS TABLE OF OBJ_USER;
/

DECLARE
  objUser OBJ_USER NOT NULL DEFAULT OBJ_USER('MARION', OBJ_USER_TYPE('USER', 3));
  tblUSERS NST_USERS NOT NULL DEFAULT NST_USERS(objUser);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO USERS(USERNAME, USER_TYPE)
  SELECT USERNAME, USER_TYPE.USER_TYPE
  FROM TABLE(tblUSERS);
END;
/
```

It raises an error of "invalid identifier" just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318272/how-to-select-from-object-type-column-in-oracle-11g).
But when I used:

```
INSERT INTO USERS(USERNAME, USER_TYPE)
SELECT USERNAME, TREAT(USER_TYPE AS OBJ_USER_TYPE).USER_TYPE
FROM TABLE(tblUSERS);
```

It raised error "too many values".
What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you show us the description of `USERS` table also type `NST_USERS` ?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar I've showed my USERS info in my edit.

Comment: Unrelated but: you don't need the `;` **and** the `/` for non PL/SQL blocks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/330315 `create ... type ...;/` will actually run that statement *twice*

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but creating types wants it. Different from other DDLs.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: You are right. I wanted to write `create table` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  objUser OBJ_USER ;
  tblUSERS NST_USERS;
BEGIN
  objUser := OBJ_USER('MARION', OBJ_USER_TYPE('USER', 3));
  tblUSERS := NST_USERS(objUser);

  INSERT INTO USERS(USERNAME, USER_TYPE)
    SELECT USERNAME, TREAT(USER_TYPE AS OBJ_USER_TYPE).USER_TYPE
     FROM
    TABLE(tblUSERS);

END;
/
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2491b/6)

Comment: Sorry but it's only a typo. I already edit it from USER_TYPE to OBJ_USER_TYPE. There's still an error.

Comment: @marionjeff can you check my edit? .. I see your [updated Question behaves as you expected too](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2491b/8)! What version of database are you using?